# Priority in ConnectedStreams

Tags: apache-flink

Is there anyway to prioritize the values of one stream over another? I have a problem where I have two streams that I connect to share state however due to the load of one of the streams the transactions seem to be queueing. If possible I would like to be able to prioritize the transactions of the connected stream that has less traffic (they're more important).

Code:

```
DataStream<Item> one; 
DataStream<Item> two;
one.connect(two).keyBy("key", "key");
```

Comment: There is no feature to prioritise a stream. How about trying to reduce the process rate for stream one if you want to speed up stream two?

Comment: I could do that upstream from flink for sure, is there a way to do that within flink?

Comment: Currently, I have not seen any API in Flink to achieve that...